# Switch read-only transaction and read-write transaction in google-cloud-spanner-hibernate

Tags: hibernate, google-cloud-spanner

I want to switch [read-write transaction](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/transactions#read-write_transactions) and [read-only transaction](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/transactions#read-only_transactions) with [google-cloud-spanner-hibernate](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-spanner-hibernate).

In JPA, `LockMode` is set for each `Query`, but not for each `Transaction`. Is there any way to control it in google-cloud-spanner-hibernate?

Comment: Can you please elaborate when you state "I want to switch read-write transaction and read-only transaction with google-cloud-spanner-hibernate"? What you are requesting here is unclear.

Comment: OK, I mean 1. Is there any config to control the transaction-mode? 2. Is there any way to switch it dynamically on runtime?

Comment: Are you asking if it’s possible to change the mode of a transaction during the execution of it? Or are you asking if during the execution of a transaction, a second transaction is being called and executed and then the execution goes back to the first transaction to be completed? Keep in mind that transactions are atomic. Meaning either all operations in a transaction get executed or none at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution [from the Hibernate forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=929739&view=previous) which may help. If you're using native Hibernate, you can do something like this:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
((SessionImplementor)session).connection().setReadOnly(true);
session.setHibernateFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);

session.beginTransaction();

... do your work ...

session.commitTransaction();
```

This will make the underlying connection use a read-only Spanner database transaction. The casting operation seems a little unusual... I'll followup and ask the Hibernate folks on what they recommend exactly but this can at least be a workaround. You can see similar casting operations done in the Spring [HibernateTransactionManager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/HibernateTransactionManager.java#L481), so maybe it is common practice.

If you are using Spring, you will have access to a more elegant method - the `@Transactional(readonly = true)` annotation. More info [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-read-only-transaction-hibernate-optimization/).

Comment: thanks so much! It's good to hear that only cast to `SessionImplementor` (i.e. Hibernate-aware but not Spanner-aware impl) enables to do that!

Comment: Np! Please also feel free to ask and also post questions to the Spanner hibernate dialect repo if you need more help: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-spanner-hibernate